# Unable to define a set with abstract get

Tags: c#

I have a problem with an accessor inherited, I can't define the set method.

My code :

```
public abstract class MotherOfDragons
{
    public abstract String DragonsName { get; }
}
```

the classes inherited :

```
public class Drogon : MotherOfDragons
{
    public override String DragonsName { get; set; }
}

public class Viserion : MotherOfDragons
{
    public override String DragonsName { get; }
}
```

It's works goo for `Viserion` but `Drogon` I have the error `CS0546`

> 'accessor' : cannot override because 'property' does not have an overridable set accessor

It is possible solve this error without add set accessor in class `MotherOfDragons` ? I want to keep this field read only expect for one case.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026546/override-get-but-not-set

Comment: Is it a solution to use a interface isntead of an abstract class. if you change: public interface MotherOfDragons and then remove the overrides

Comment: I can't do `MotherOfDragons` as Interface, I implement some methods inside and it inherit from an other class

Comment: It's somewhat bad design. Typically if you have `abstract class`, then there will be some functionality (otherwise it should be an [interface](http://stackoverflow.com/q/747517/1997232), e.g. if you plan to have `List<MotherDragons>` to hold different inherited dragons). If your problem is to set name when constructing inherited object, then simply add `protected` setter or method to base class. I think `public abstract string DragonsName { get; protected set; }` is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @sircodesalot

I finally made this :

```
public class Drogon : MotherOfDragons
{
    private String dragonsName;
    public override String DragonsName { get { return dragonsName; } }

    public void Change_DragonsName(String name)
    {
        dragonsName = name;
    }
}
```

It works, not like a `set`, but it works.

Comment: If you don't want to change base value, you can simply do `public new string DragonsName { get; set; }` (no need for a field or method).

Comment: I have try this at first but it return an error `cs0534 class does not implement inherited abstract member`

Comment: Ouch, my bad. Missed `abstract` base class (for normal `virtual` property that would work).