# DataGridView Event Before DataSource Changes

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Is there someway I could trigger **DataSourceChanging** event in DataGridView. The DataGridView has **DataSourceChanged** event which (I believe) after DataSource is bound to the DataGridView. I want to do some stuff before the property gets changed.

A Sample code of mine...

```
private void LoadGrid()
{
    //  I do some things like saving user settings here
    DtgRefundAssign.DataSource = BLL.GetDataSource(parameter1, parameter2); //Just to illustrate
    //  And restore them after the datasource is bound

}
```

I need to do similar stuffs in many forms. Just thinking to develop a common procedure which does this, whenever the datasource is changed. The restoring part can be done using DataSourceChanged event... But which event should I handle to do the saving part ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done this myself, but DataGridView isn't sealed so you should be able to create a new class that inherits from it. Create a new event "DataSourceChanging", then override the DataSource property's Setter so that it first raises that event, *then* actually sets the property on the parent class.

You'd then simply use that datagridview in place of the default one, and hook up your save logic to DataSourceChanging.

Comment: Yes..  But the DataSource Property is not virtual...  Is there a way I could override it ?

Comment: I didn't think of that. :( If it won't let you override it through some kind of trickery, you could create another property and have that one raise the event then set the parents datasource. A bit messy, but it'll work. But check the second answer to this question for a possible workaround (I haven't tried that either): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82437/why-is-it-impossible-to-override-a-getter-only-property-and-add-a-setter

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shadows/new property in the sub class using new/shadows keywords depending on whether you use c# or vb.net, since you cant override it. Use base.DataSource calls in the sub class to access the base class's property and use this.DataSource in the sub class to access the new DataSource property. :D