# How to sort DataGridView data when virtual mode Enable

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

i have completed my code for DataGridView with virtual data loading and it is working but i want sorting also should work when i will click on column header column. i read idea from this thread `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087074/c-sharp-datagridview-virtual-mode-enable-sorting`

but still could not achieve how to enable sorting when DataGridView virtual mode is enabled.

here i am posting full code and also apologized for posting my big code. so please some one rectify my code or give me small code portion which help me to sort grid data along with virtual data loading. sorting glyph should come too when column header will be clicked.

### here is full code

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string connectionString =
        "Initial Catalog=Test1;Data Source=BBATRIDIP\\SQLSERVER2008R2;" +
        "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False";
        private string table = "Orders";

        private Cache memoryCache=null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
            this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode =
            DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            this.dataGridView1.CellValueNeeded += new DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded);

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender,DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Value = memoryCache.RetrieveElement(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataRetriever retriever = new DataRetriever(connectionString, table,"OrderID");
                memoryCache = new Cache(retriever, 16);
                foreach (DataColumn column in retriever.Columns)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                }
                this.dataGridView1.RowCount = retriever.RowCount;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection could not be established. " + "Verify that the connection string is valid.");
                Application.Exit();
            }

            // Adjust the column widths based on the displayed values. 
            this.dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);

        }

        private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // this routine will add row no to HeaderCell which comes left most
            var grid = sender as DataGridView;
            var rowIdx = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();

            var centerFormat = new StringFormat()
            {
                // right alignment might actually make more sense for numbers
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            };

            var headerBounds = new Rectangle(e.RowBounds.Left, e.RowBounds.Top, grid.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(rowIdx, this.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, headerBounds, centerFormat);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //this.ValidateChildren();// force value be set to the underlying list.

            string strSortCol = this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
            string strSortOrder = "";

            if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending;
                strSortOrder = " ASC";
            }
            else if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
                strSortOrder = " DESC";
            }

            DataRetriever retriever = new DataRetriever(connectionString, table, strSortCol);
            //dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }


    }


public interface IDataPageRetriever
{
    DataTable SupplyPageOfData(int lowerPageBoundary, int rowsPerPage);
}

public class DataRetriever : IDataPageRetriever
{
    private string tableName;
    private SqlCommand command;
    private string sortColumn;

    public DataRetriever(string connectionString, string tableName, string sortColumn)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        command = connection.CreateCommand();
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.sortColumn = sortColumn;
    }

    private int rowCountValue = -1;

    public int RowCount
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
            if (rowCountValue != -1)
            {
                return rowCountValue;
            }

            // Retrieve the row count from the database.
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName;
            rowCountValue = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            return rowCountValue;
        }
    }

    private DataColumnCollection columnsValue;

    public DataColumnCollection Columns
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
            if (columnsValue != null)
            {
                return columnsValue;
            }

            // Retrieve the column information from the database.
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
            columnsValue = table.Columns;
            return columnsValue;
        }
    }

    private string commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue = null;

    private string CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
            if (commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue != null)
            {
                return commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue;
            }

            // Store a list of column names for use in the 
            // SupplyPageOfData method.
            System.Text.StringBuilder commaSeparatedColumnNames =
                new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            bool firstColumn = true;
            foreach (DataColumn column in Columns)
            {
                if (!firstColumn)
                {
                    commaSeparatedColumnNames.Append(", ");
                }
                commaSeparatedColumnNames.Append(column.ColumnName);
                firstColumn = false;
            }

            commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue =
                commaSeparatedColumnNames.ToString();
            return commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue;
        }
    }

    // Declare variables to be reused by the SupplyPageOfData method. 
    private string columnToSortBy;
    private SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    public DataTable SupplyPageOfData(int lowerPageBoundary, int rowsPerPage)
    {
        // Store the name of the ID column. This column must contain unique  
        // values so the SQL below will work properly. 
        if (columnToSortBy == null)
        {
            columnToSortBy = this.Columns[0].ColumnName;
        }

        if (!this.Columns[columnToSortBy].Unique)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(
                "Column {0} must contain unique values.", columnToSortBy));
        }

        // Retrieve the specified number of rows from the database, starting 
        // with the row specified by the lowerPageBoundary parameter.
        command.CommandText = "Select Top " + rowsPerPage + " " +
            CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames + " From " + tableName +
            " WHERE " + columnToSortBy + " NOT IN (SELECT TOP " +
            lowerPageBoundary + " " + columnToSortBy + " From " +
            tableName + " Order By " + sortColumn +
            ") Order By " + sortColumn;
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        adapter.Fill(table);
        return table;
    }

}


public class Cache
{
    private static int RowsPerPage;

    // Represents one page of data.   
    public struct DataPage
    {
        public DataTable table;
        private int lowestIndexValue;
        private int highestIndexValue;

        public DataPage(DataTable table, int rowIndex)
        {
            this.table = table;
            lowestIndexValue = MapToLowerBoundary(rowIndex);
            highestIndexValue = MapToUpperBoundary(rowIndex);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(lowestIndexValue >= 0);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(highestIndexValue >= 0);
        }

        public int LowestIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return lowestIndexValue;
            }
        }

        public int HighestIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return highestIndexValue;
            }
        }

        public static int MapToLowerBoundary(int rowIndex)
        {
            // Return the lowest index of a page containing the given index. 
            return (rowIndex / RowsPerPage) * RowsPerPage;
        }

        private static int MapToUpperBoundary(int rowIndex)
        {
            // Return the highest index of a page containing the given index. 
            return MapToLowerBoundary(rowIndex) + RowsPerPage - 1;
        }
    }

    private DataPage[] cachePages;
    private IDataPageRetriever dataSupply;

    public Cache(IDataPageRetriever dataSupplier, int rowsPerPage)
    {
        dataSupply = dataSupplier;
        Cache.RowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
        LoadFirstTwoPages();
    }

    // Sets the value of the element parameter if the value is in the cache. 
    private bool IfPageCached_ThenSetElement(int rowIndex,
        int columnIndex, ref string element)
    {
        if (IsRowCachedInPage(0, rowIndex))
        {
            element = cachePages[0].table
                .Rows[rowIndex % RowsPerPage][columnIndex].ToString();
            return true;
        }
        else if (IsRowCachedInPage(1, rowIndex))
        {
            element = cachePages[1].table
                .Rows[rowIndex % RowsPerPage][columnIndex].ToString();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public string RetrieveElement(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        string element = null;

        if (IfPageCached_ThenSetElement(rowIndex, columnIndex, ref element))
        {
            return element;
        }
        else
        {
            return RetrieveData_CacheIt_ThenReturnElement(
                rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }
    }

    private void LoadFirstTwoPages()
    {
        cachePages = new DataPage[]{
        new DataPage(dataSupply.SupplyPageOfData(
            DataPage.MapToLowerBoundary(0), RowsPerPage), 0), 
        new DataPage(dataSupply.SupplyPageOfData(
            DataPage.MapToLowerBoundary(RowsPerPage), 
            RowsPerPage), RowsPerPage)};
    }

    private string RetrieveData_CacheIt_ThenReturnElement(
        int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        // Retrieve a page worth of data containing the requested value.
        DataTable table = dataSupply.SupplyPageOfData(
            DataPage.MapToLowerBoundary(rowIndex), RowsPerPage);

        // Replace the cached page furthest from the requested cell 
        // with a new page containing the newly retrieved data.
        cachePages[GetIndexToUnusedPage(rowIndex)] = new DataPage(table, rowIndex);

        return RetrieveElement(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }

    // Returns the index of the cached page most distant from the given index 
    // and therefore least likely to be reused. 
    private int GetIndexToUnusedPage(int rowIndex)
    {
        if (rowIndex > cachePages[0].HighestIndex &&
            rowIndex > cachePages[1].HighestIndex)
        {
            int offsetFromPage0 = rowIndex - cachePages[0].HighestIndex;
            int offsetFromPage1 = rowIndex - cachePages[1].HighestIndex;
            if (offsetFromPage0 < offsetFromPage1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int offsetFromPage0 = cachePages[0].LowestIndex - rowIndex;
            int offsetFromPage1 = cachePages[1].LowestIndex - rowIndex;
            if (offsetFromPage0 < offsetFromPage1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

    }

    // Returns a value indicating whether the given row index is contained 
    // in the given DataPage.  
    private bool IsRowCachedInPage(int pageNumber, int rowIndex)
    {
        return rowIndex <= cachePages[pageNumber].HighestIndex &&
            rowIndex >= cachePages[pageNumber].LowestIndex;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the sorting issue when using datagridview virtual mode for load data on demand. here i will post once again my full working code. data fetch from Northwind order table.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;


namespace DGVirtualScroll
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string connectionString =
        "Initial Catalog=Test1;Data Source=BBATRIDIP\\SQLSERVER2008R2;" +
        "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False";
        private string table = "Orders";

        int Page_Size = 16;
        private string strPrevSortCol = "";
        private string strSortCol = "OrderID";
        private string strSortOrder = "ASC";

        private Cache memoryCache=null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // use DoubleBuffered to remove flicker when user load frequently clicking on load button
            typeof(DataGridView).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
                null,
                this.dataGridView1,
                new object[] { true });

            this.dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
            this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            this.dataGridView1.CellValueNeeded += new DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender,DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Value = memoryCache.RetrieveElement(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Resetsort();
            LoadData(strSortCol, strSortOrder);
        }

        private void Resetsort()
        {
            strPrevSortCol = "OrderID";
            strSortCol = "OrderID";
            strSortOrder = "ASC";
        }

        private void LoadData(string strSortCol, string strSortOrder)
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

            try
            {
                DataRetriever retriever = new DataRetriever(connectionString, table, strSortCol + " " + strSortOrder);
                memoryCache = new Cache(retriever, Page_Size);
                //foreach (DataColumn column in retriever.Columns)
                //{
                //    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                //}

                retriever.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList().ForEach(n => dataGridView1.Columns.Add(n.ColumnName, n.ColumnName));
                this.dataGridView1.RowCount = retriever.RowCount;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection could not be established. " + "Verify that the connection string is valid.");
                Application.Exit();
            }

            // Adjust the column widths based on the displayed values. 
            this.dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);

            if (strSortOrder == "ASC")
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[strSortCol].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
            else
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[strSortCol].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending;

        }

        private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // this routine will add row no to HeaderCell which comes left most
            var grid = sender as DataGridView;
            var rowIdx = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();

            var centerFormat = new StringFormat()
            {
                // right alignment might actually make more sense for numbers
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            };

            var headerBounds = new Rectangle(e.RowBounds.Left, e.RowBounds.Top, grid.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(rowIdx, this.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, headerBounds, centerFormat);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            string strSortCol = this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;

            if (strPrevSortCol.Trim().ToUpper() != strSortCol.Trim().ToUpper())
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[strPrevSortCol].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.None;
                strPrevSortCol = strSortCol;
                strSortOrder = "ASC";
            }

            if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending;
                strSortOrder = "DESC";
            }
            else if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
                strSortOrder = "ASC";
            }
            else
            {
                if (strSortOrder == "ASC")
                    this.dataGridView1.Columns[strSortCol].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
                else
                    this.dataGridView1.Columns[strSortCol].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending;

            }

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            DataRetriever retriever = new DataRetriever(connectionString, table, strSortCol + " " + strSortOrder);
            memoryCache = new Cache(retriever, Page_Size);
            this.dataGridView1.RowCount = retriever.RowCount;
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }


    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DGVirtualScroll
{
    public interface IDataPageRetriever
    {
        DataTable SupplyPageOfData(int lowerPageBoundary, int rowsPerPage);
    }

    public class DataRetriever : IDataPageRetriever
    {
        private string tableName;
        private SqlCommand command;
        private string sortColumn;

        public DataRetriever(string connectionString, string tableName, string sortColumn)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            this.tableName = tableName;
            this.sortColumn = sortColumn;
        }

        private int rowCountValue = -1;

        public int RowCount
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
                if (rowCountValue != -1)
                {
                    return rowCountValue;
                }

                // Retrieve the row count from the database.
                command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName;
                rowCountValue = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                return rowCountValue;
            }
        }

        private DataColumnCollection columnsValue;

        public DataColumnCollection Columns
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
                if (columnsValue != null)
                {
                    return columnsValue;
                }

                // Retrieve the column information from the database.
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
                columnsValue = table.Columns;
                return columnsValue;
            }
        }

        private string commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue = null;

        private string CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
                if (commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue != null)
                {
                    return commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue;
                }

                // Store a list of column names for use in the 
                // SupplyPageOfData method.
                System.Text.StringBuilder commaSeparatedColumnNames =
                    new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                bool firstColumn = true;
                foreach (DataColumn column in Columns)
                {
                    if (!firstColumn)
                    {
                        commaSeparatedColumnNames.Append(", ");
                    }
                    commaSeparatedColumnNames.Append(column.ColumnName);
                    firstColumn = false;
                }

                commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue =
                    commaSeparatedColumnNames.ToString();
                return commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue;
            }
        }

        // Declare variables to be reused by the SupplyPageOfData method. 
        private string columnToSortBy;
        private SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        public DataTable SupplyPageOfData(int lowerPageBoundary, int rowsPerPage)
        {
            // Store the name of the ID column. This column must contain unique  
            // values so the SQL below will work properly. 
            if (columnToSortBy == null)
            {
                columnToSortBy = this.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            }

            if (!this.Columns[columnToSortBy].Unique)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(
                    "Column {0} must contain unique values.", columnToSortBy));
            }

            // Retrieve the specified number of rows from the database, starting 
            // with the row specified by the lowerPageBoundary parameter.
            command.CommandText = "Select Top " + rowsPerPage + " " +
                CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames + " From " + tableName +
                " WHERE " + columnToSortBy + " NOT IN (SELECT TOP " +
                lowerPageBoundary + " " + columnToSortBy + " From " +
                tableName + " Order By " + sortColumn + 
                ") Order By " + sortColumn ;
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            return table;
        }

    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DGVirtualScroll
{
    public class Cache
    {
        private static int RowsPerPage;

        // Represents one page of data.   
        public struct DataPage
        {
            public DataTable table;
            private int lowestIndexValue;
            private int highestIndexValue;

            public DataPage(DataTable table, int rowIndex)
            {
                this.table = table;
                lowestIndexValue = MapToLowerBoundary(rowIndex);
                highestIndexValue = MapToUpperBoundary(rowIndex);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(lowestIndexValue >= 0);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(highestIndexValue >= 0);
            }

            public int LowestIndex
            {
                get
                {
                    return lowestIndexValue;
                }
            }

            public int HighestIndex
            {
                get
                {
                    return highestIndexValue;
                }
            }

            public static int MapToLowerBoundary(int rowIndex)
            {
                // Return the lowest index of a page containing the given index. 
                return (rowIndex / RowsPerPage) * RowsPerPage;
            }

            private static int MapToUpperBoundary(int rowIndex)
            {
                // Return the highest index of a page containing the given index. 
                return MapToLowerBoundary(rowIndex) + RowsPerPage - 1;
            }
        }

        private DataPage[] cachePages;
        private IDataPageRetriever dataSupply;

        public Cache(IDataPageRetriever dataSupplier, int rowsPerPage)
        {
            dataSupply = dataSupplier;
            Cache.RowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
            LoadFirstTwoPages();
        }

        // Sets the value of the element parameter if the value is in the cache. 
        private bool IfPageCached_ThenSetElement(int rowIndex,
            int columnIndex, ref string element)
        {
            if (IsRowCachedInPage(0, rowIndex))
            {
                element = cachePages[0].table
                    .Rows[rowIndex % RowsPerPage][columnIndex].ToString();
                return true;
            }
            else if (IsRowCachedInPage(1, rowIndex))
            {
                element = cachePages[1].table
                    .Rows[rowIndex % RowsPerPage][columnIndex].ToString();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public string RetrieveElement(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            string element = null;

            if (IfPageCached_ThenSetElement(rowIndex, columnIndex, ref element))
            {
                return element;
            }
            else
            {
                return RetrieveData_CacheIt_ThenReturnElement(
                    rowIndex, columnIndex);
            }
        }

        private void LoadFirstTwoPages()
        {
            cachePages = new DataPage[]
            {
                new DataPage(dataSupply.SupplyPageOfData(DataPage.MapToLowerBoundary(0), RowsPerPage), 0), 
                new DataPage(dataSupply.SupplyPageOfData(DataPage.MapToLowerBoundary(RowsPerPage), RowsPerPage), RowsPerPage)
            };
        }

        private string RetrieveData_CacheIt_ThenReturnElement(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            // Retrieve a page worth of data containing the requested value.
            DataTable table = dataSupply.SupplyPageOfData(
                DataPage.MapToLowerBoundary(rowIndex), RowsPerPage);

            // Replace the cached page furthest from the requested cell 
            // with a new page containing the newly retrieved data.
            cachePages[GetIndexToUnusedPage(rowIndex)] = new DataPage(table, rowIndex);

            return RetrieveElement(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }

        // Returns the index of the cached page most distant from the given index 
        // and therefore least likely to be reused. 
        private int GetIndexToUnusedPage(int rowIndex)
        {
            if (rowIndex > cachePages[0].HighestIndex &&
                rowIndex > cachePages[1].HighestIndex)
            {
                int offsetFromPage0 = rowIndex - cachePages[0].HighestIndex;
                int offsetFromPage1 = rowIndex - cachePages[1].HighestIndex;
                if (offsetFromPage0 < offsetFromPage1)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int offsetFromPage0 = cachePages[0].LowestIndex - rowIndex;
                int offsetFromPage1 = cachePages[1].LowestIndex - rowIndex;
                if (offsetFromPage0 < offsetFromPage1)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }

        }

        // Returns a value indicating whether the given row index is contained 
        // in the given DataPage.  
        private bool IsRowCachedInPage(int pageNumber, int rowIndex)
        {
            return rowIndex <= cachePages[pageNumber].HighestIndex &&
                rowIndex >= cachePages[pageNumber].LowestIndex;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here i am going post more or less same code for same job but there is bit difference in approach. full code as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
namespace DGVirtualScroll
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string connectionString =
        "Initial Catalog=Test1;Data Source=BBATRIDIP\\SQLSERVER2008R2;" +
        "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False";
        private string table = "Orders";
        private string strSortCol = "OrderID";
        private string strSortOrder = "ASC";

        private Cache memoryCache=null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            typeof(DataGridView).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
                null,
                this.dataGridView1,
                new object[] { true });

            this.dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
            this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            this.dataGridView1.CellValueNeeded += new DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender,DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Value = memoryCache.RetrieveElement(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Resetsort();
            LoadData(strSortCol, strSortOrder);
        }

        private void Resetsort()
        {
            strSortCol = "OrderID";
            strSortOrder = "ASC";
        }

        private void LoadData(string strSortCol, string strSortOrder)
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

            try
            {
                DataRetriever retriever = new DataRetriever(connectionString, table, strSortCol, strSortOrder);
                memoryCache = new Cache(retriever, 16);
                foreach (DataColumn column in retriever.Columns)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                }
                this.dataGridView1.RowCount = retriever.RowCount;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection could not be established. " + "Verify that the connection string is valid.");
                Application.Exit();
            }

            // Adjust the column widths based on the displayed values. 
            this.dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);
            if (strSortOrder == "ASC")
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[strSortCol].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
            else
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[strSortCol].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending;

        }

        private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // this routine will add row no to HeaderCell which comes left most
            var grid = sender as DataGridView;
            var rowIdx = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();

            var centerFormat = new StringFormat()
            {
                // right alignment might actually make more sense for numbers
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
            };

            var headerBounds = new Rectangle(e.RowBounds.Left, e.RowBounds.Top, grid.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(rowIdx, this.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, headerBounds, centerFormat);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (strSortCol.Trim().ToUpper() != this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Trim().ToUpper())
            {
                strSortOrder = "ASC";
            }
            else
            {
                strSortOrder = (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending ? "DESC" : "ASC");
            }
            strSortCol = this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
            LoadData(strSortCol, strSortOrder);
        }

        void RefreshGrid()
        {
            //dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            //dataGridView1.Refresh();
            //dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            //LoadData(strSortCol, strSortOrder);
        }

    }
}



******************
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DGVirtualScroll
{
    public interface IDataPageRetriever
    {
        DataTable SupplyPageOfData(int lowerPageBoundary, int rowsPerPage);
    }

    public class DataRetriever : IDataPageRetriever
    {
        private string tableName;
        private SqlCommand command;
        private string sortColumn;
        private string Sortorder;

        public DataRetriever(string connectionString, string tableName, string sortColumn,string Sortorder)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            this.tableName = tableName;
            this.sortColumn = sortColumn;
            this.Sortorder = (Sortorder.Trim() == "" ? "ASC" : Sortorder.Trim());
        }

        private int rowCountValue = -1;

        public int RowCount
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
                if (rowCountValue != -1)
                {
                    return rowCountValue;
                }

                // Retrieve the row count from the database.
                command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName;
                rowCountValue = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                return rowCountValue;
            }
        }

        private DataColumnCollection columnsValue;

        public DataColumnCollection Columns
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
                if (columnsValue != null)
                {
                    return columnsValue;
                }

                // Retrieve the column information from the database.
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
                columnsValue = table.Columns;
                return columnsValue;
            }
        }

        private string commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue = null;

        private string CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the existing value if it has already been determined. 
                if (commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue != null)
                {
                    return commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue;
                }

                // Store a list of column names for use in the 
                // SupplyPageOfData method.
                System.Text.StringBuilder commaSeparatedColumnNames =
                    new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                bool firstColumn = true;
                foreach (DataColumn column in Columns)
                {
                    if (!firstColumn)
                    {
                        commaSeparatedColumnNames.Append(", ");
                    }
                    commaSeparatedColumnNames.Append(column.ColumnName);
                    firstColumn = false;
                }

                commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue =
                    commaSeparatedColumnNames.ToString();
                return commaSeparatedListOfColumnNamesValue;
            }
        }

        // Declare variables to be reused by the SupplyPageOfData method. 
        private string columnToSortBy;
        private SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        public DataTable SupplyPageOfData(int lowerPageBoundary, int rowsPerPage)
        {
            // Store the name of the ID column. This column must contain unique  
            // values so the SQL below will work properly. 
            if (columnToSortBy == null)
            {
                columnToSortBy = this.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            }

            if (!this.Columns[columnToSortBy].Unique)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(
                    "Column {0} must contain unique values.", columnToSortBy));
            }

            // Retrieve the specified number of rows from the database, starting 
            // with the row specified by the lowerPageBoundary parameter.
            command.CommandText = "Select Top " + rowsPerPage + " " +
                CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames + " From " + tableName +
                " WHERE " + columnToSortBy + " NOT IN (SELECT TOP " +
                lowerPageBoundary + " " + columnToSortBy + " From " +
                tableName + " Order By " + sortColumn + " "+Sortorder+
                ") Order By " + sortColumn + " " + Sortorder;
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            return table;
        }

    }
}

*****************
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DGVirtualScroll
{
    public class Cache
    {
        private static int RowsPerPage;

        // Represents one page of data.   
        public struct DataPage
        {
            public DataTable table;
            private int lowestIndexValue;
            private int highestIndexValue;

            public DataPage(DataTable table, int rowIndex)
            {
                this.table = table;
                lowestIndexValue = MapToLowerBoundary(rowIndex);
                highestIndexValue = MapToUpperBoundary(rowIndex);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(lowestIndexValue >= 0);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(highestIndexValue >= 0);
            }

            public int LowestIndex
            {
                get
                {
                    return lowestIndexValue;
                }
            }

            public int HighestIndex
            {
                get
                {
                    return highestIndexValue;
                }
            }

            public static int MapToLowerBoundary(int rowIndex)
            {
                // Return the lowest index of a page containing the given index. 
                return (rowIndex / RowsPerPage) * RowsPerPage;
            }

            private static int MapToUpperBoundary(int rowIndex)
            {
                // Return the highest index of a page containing the given index. 
                return MapToLowerBoundary(rowIndex) + RowsPerPage - 1;
            }
        }

        private DataPage[] cachePages;
        private IDataPageRetriever dataSupply;

        public Cache(IDataPageRetriever dataSupplier, int rowsPerPage)
        {
            dataSupply = dataSupplier;
            Cache.RowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
            LoadFirstTwoPages();
        }

        // Sets the value of the element parameter if the value is in the cache. 
        private bool IfPageCached_ThenSetElement(int rowIndex,
            int columnIndex, ref string element)
        {
            if (IsRowCachedInPage(0, rowIndex))
            {
                element = cachePages[0].table
                    .Rows[rowIndex % RowsPerPage][columnIndex].ToString();
                return true;
            }
            else if (IsRowCachedInPage(1, rowIndex))
            {
                element = cachePages[1].table
                    .Rows[rowIndex % RowsPerPage][columnIndex].ToString();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public string RetrieveElement(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            string element = null;

            if (IfPageCached_ThenSetElement(rowIndex, columnIndex, ref element))
            {
                return element;
            }
            else
            {
                return RetrieveData_CacheIt_ThenReturnElement(
                    rowIndex, columnIndex);
            }
        }

        private void LoadFirstTwoPages()
        {
            cachePages = new DataPage[]
            {
                new DataPage(dataSupply.SupplyPageOfData(DataPage.MapToLowerBoundary(0), RowsPerPage), 0), 
                new DataPage(dataSupply.SupplyPageOfData(DataPage.MapToLowerBoundary(RowsPerPage), RowsPerPage), RowsPerPage)
            };
        }

        private string RetrieveData_CacheIt_ThenReturnElement(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            // Retrieve a page worth of data containing the requested value.
            DataTable table = dataSupply.SupplyPageOfData(
                DataPage.MapToLowerBoundary(rowIndex), RowsPerPage);

            // Replace the cached page furthest from the requested cell 
            // with a new page containing the newly retrieved data.
            cachePages[GetIndexToUnusedPage(rowIndex)] = new DataPage(table, rowIndex);

            return RetrieveElement(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }

        // Returns the index of the cached page most distant from the given index 
        // and therefore least likely to be reused. 
        private int GetIndexToUnusedPage(int rowIndex)
        {
            if (rowIndex > cachePages[0].HighestIndex &&
                rowIndex > cachePages[1].HighestIndex)
            {
                int offsetFromPage0 = rowIndex - cachePages[0].HighestIndex;
                int offsetFromPage1 = rowIndex - cachePages[1].HighestIndex;
                if (offsetFromPage0 < offsetFromPage1)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int offsetFromPage0 = cachePages[0].LowestIndex - rowIndex;
                int offsetFromPage1 = cachePages[1].LowestIndex - rowIndex;
                if (offsetFromPage0 < offsetFromPage1)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }

        }

        // Returns a value indicating whether the given row index is contained 
        // in the given DataPage.  
        private bool IsRowCachedInPage(int pageNumber, int rowIndex)
        {
            return rowIndex <= cachePages[pageNumber].HighestIndex &&
                rowIndex >= cachePages[pageNumber].LowestIndex;
        }

    }
}
```