# C# architecture inheritage override different signature?

Tags: c#, inheritance, architecture, overriding

I have three classes: `CookedItem` : `ConsomableItem` : `Item`

`Item` implements this method:

```
protected void Initialize(string name,TypeItem type) {...}
```

`ConsomableItem` implements this method:

```
protected void Initialize(float duration,string name,TypeItem type) {...}
```

Now here is my problem. The correct method to call for `CookedItem` is `ConsomableItem.Initialize()`.

Can I hide the method Item.Initialize()`to only see the method`ConsomableItem.Initialize()`?

I can't use `override` because the signatures are different.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is this something you should be using constructors for?

Comment: No -  `CookedItem` is a `ConsomableItem` and indirectly an `Item` so it has rights to both functions.

Comment: I cannot use constructors because i'm using Unity but thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You are violating the third principal of the SOLID. The Liskov Substitution Principal. Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle) to understand what it is.

Basically you have built a wrong inheritance.

What you should be doing is to `ICookable` and `IConsumable` interfaces, as behaviours. Then you will have two different item class implementations(you may still abstract them in an abstract class).

Answer (score 0):

In your class hierarchy `Initialize` methods are [protected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx), so they won't be visible to classes that are not in this inheritance hierarchy, so it is up to you to design a better API for **external** clients.

As for hiding the methods **inside** the hierarchy, I don't think it's possible, even if the methods were virtual, compiler would not allow you to change access modifiers of the methods.
To find out more about why it's disallowed, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236909/why-cant-we-change-access-modifier-while-overriding-methods-in-c)

In addition to breaking LSP as @Tolga Evcimen mentioned, it does not make a lot of sense to have this inheritance hierarchy. 
Inheritance is thought of as **is-a** relationship, now is `CookedItem` really an `Item`, if calling `Initialize` methods that belong to item do not make sense / yield inconsistent object state?

Comment: OP wants to hide the function from `CookedItem` which inherits from `Item`.

Comment: @DStanley - I understand that, however, it is not possible - I've added an explanation why