# Unity doesn't run my c# scripts in any component and in any project. It reads all the values though

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new on unity and I am dealing with a problem. Unity doesn't run my c# scripts in any component and in any project. Although unity reads all the values from the script, it won't execute the game as expected. On the script components it shows that the scripts are disabled, as you can see on the following screenshot. I should probably mention that the game was working fine until this problem came from nowhere. I don't think that it's a problem from the script, because this happens even on completely empty scripts. [This is the script component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29HwG.jpg) [Empty c# script with the same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek0Fb.png). I have tried to reinstall unity 2 times(nothing happens). I have tried to reimport all the scripts(nothing happens). I have tried to reimport all the assets(nothing happens). Any help would be really appreciated.
[This is the whole scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBNiw.png)

This is the whole script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary
{
    public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;
}    

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float tilt;
    public Boundary boundary;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public GameObject shot;
    public Transform shotSpawn;
    public float fireRate;
    private float nextFire;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            Instantiate(shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rb.velocity = movement * speed;

        rb.position = new Vector3
            (
            Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
            0.0f,
            Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
            );
        rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rb.velocity.x * -tilt);
    }


}
```

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8d0o.png)

Comment: Could we take a look at your script?

Comment: The script is not disabled actually, in that case the tick sign wouldn't be there. Can you please share your scene screenshot with the gameobject which has the script selected? Also the whole script?

Comment: Sure check bellow

Comment: ok yeah already did it :)

Comment: woops, We lost the link the the screen shot of the scene. You can maybe add in in a comment here. Regarding your problem, are you sure there is absolutely no error in the console in the editor?

Comment: yeah i saw and i instantly added that again

Comment: yep there are no errors. happens on every project

Comment: Use `Debug.Log`. Put it in the `Start` and `Update` function then click play and check the Console tab. They should work and if they do, your question will no longer be valid. If they don't then there is a big issue. I don't expect you to have a problem with this

Comment: Check for a screenshot under my code. This is what the console shows

Comment: @CrazyDirewolf Well... the code is running. Try using standard debugging techniques.

Comment: The script is being executed this means that your title and body is wrong. *"Unity doesn't run my c# scripts in any component"* cannot be possible. You may want to modify your question and mention what exactly is not working. Be specific.

Comment: @CrazyDirewolf I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

First off - the script has the embedded assumption that the Input Manager  (Project settings / Input) has an axis called "Fire1". While this is true by default, I've wittnesed it change (usually by means of a 3rd party script) so please verify that you have that axis in your project. You can try creating a new project and placing your scripts there.

Secondly, I am not sure if you are doing the correct thing with your rigidbody, you seem to be manually changing its position, so you are effectively overriding any computations that you ask for earlier (by setting the velocity), you should pick one approach and stick with it, i.e. either tick 'isKinematic' on the rigidbody and control its position by hand, or just trust PhysiX and modify velocity (makes more sense to me). Mixed approach can give some unexpected results in a lot of cases, where it would sort of work but not quite as expected

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is not working in your code, but if the problem is your FixedUpdateMethod, then it is because you changed the access level of the method.

[This is a link explaining the why you can't change access levels when overriding a method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236909/why-cant-we-change-access-modifier-while-overriding-methods-in-c)

Unity's API has `FixedUpdate()` at default access level so try changing taking private off of it.

Should look something like this:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float tilt;
    public Boundary boundary;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public GameObject shot;
    public Transform shotSpawn;
    public float fireRate;
    private float nextFire;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            Instantiate(shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }
    }

   void FixedUpdate() //no longer has private keyword appended to method
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rb.velocity = movement * speed;

        rb.position = new Vector3
            (
            Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
            0.0f,
            Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
            );
        rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rb.velocity.x * -tilt);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, took a while to find the solution
you may have pause on errors on in your unity debug console, it pause the execution of the scripts if there is any errors, **There is a tab in here labelled 'Error Pause'. If it is highlighted, click it to disable it**